Call to view function, which returns a bytes value, got error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
I have this test smart contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

contract TestSomething {
    bytes state;
    bytes32 state32;
    constructor() {}

    function testABIEncodePacked() public {
        state32 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(state, state));
        state = abi.encodePacked(state32);
    }

    function getState() public view returns (bytes memory) {
        return state;
    }

    function getState32() public view returns (bytes32) {
        return state32;
    }
}


Then, I use solc,
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.8.26+commit.8a97fa7a.Linux.g++

to generate a golang file of this smart contract:
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf ./build

solc --version

solc --bin TestSomething.sol -o build
solc --abi TestSomething.sol -o build

rm -rf ./generated/TestSomething
mkdir -p generated/TestSomething

# Generate smart contract as `go` file
abigen --bin=./build/TestSomething.bin --abi=./build/TestSomething.abi --pkg=TestSomething --out=generated/TestSomething/TestSomething.go

Finaly, I deploy the contract to my local network (ganache), and try to call getState() and getState32() functions,
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/NguyenHiu/test-signature/contracts/generated/TestSomething"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    privateKeyHex := "abf82ff96b463e9d82b83cb9bb450fe87e6166d4db6d7021d0c71d7e960d5abe"
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(privateKeyHex)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(privateKey)
    }

    auth, err := bind.NewKeyedTransactorWithChainID(privateKey, big.NewInt(1337))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client, err := ethclient.Dial("http://127.0.0.1:8545")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    contractAddr, _, instance, err := TestSomething.DeployTestSomething(auth, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("address: %v\n", contractAddr)

    instance.TestABIEncodePacked(auth)

    callOpts := &bind.CallOpts{Context: context.Background()}
    res, err := instance.GetState(callOpts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("res: %v\n", res)
    }

    res32, err := instance.GetState32(callOpts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("res32: %v\n", res32)
    }
}


And I got this,
$ go run .
address: 0xB5AE3e2883934457cb593793f034b401867e1372
error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
res32: [197 210 70 1 134 247 35 60 146 126 125 178 220 199 3 192 229 0 182 83 202 130 39 59 123 250 216 4 93 133 164 112]

The getState() function got an invalid opcode error. I don't get why this happens, can someone please help me,

It’s possibly due to the incompatibility of compiler version (i.e., 0.8.26) with the default EVM version used by your solc. For compiler version 0.8.26, you should use the EVM version as cancun.
So, you can either try to update/reinstall your solc to bring it up to the latest version or use a lower compiler version like 0.8.24 or below. Then, you can compile and deploy again.

It worked! Thank you so much!

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
